# Как сериализовать объект, не реализующий ни одного из интерфейсов сериализации?

Tags: java, сериализация

Здравствуйте. Для сериализации объекта надо, чтобы он реализовывал интерфейс `java.io.Serializable` или `java.io.Externalizable`. Иначе будет ошибка `java.io.NotSerializableException`. Но как быть, если я использую *сторонние* библиотеки без исходного кода и мне надо сериализация одного из объектов этой библиотеки? 
Этот объект находится внутри моего класса для сериализации (одно из полей). Предположим также, что внутри этого объекта (из сторонней библиотеки) также находятся поля классов, не реализующих ни один из интерфейсов сериализации.

Comment: А если сделать собственную обертку над нужным обьектом? То есть свой класс наследованный от него и реализующий интерфейс Serializable?

Comment: да. Но если внутри объекта еще объекты, объекты, объекты.... .... ... Так терпения не хватит разбираться, что еще не обернул. Поэтому хочется какой-нибудь красивый способ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, что если объекты из сторонних библиотек не предоставляют возможность сериализации, то заставить их сериализоваться *"нативно"* у вас не получится.

Обойти данную проблему можно достаточно простым способом - **обернуть каждый объект** `Entity` в, например, `EntitySerialiazbleProxy`, где написать соответствующие сериализации всех необходимых полей.

Также возможно *(этот способ хуже, но имеет право на жизнь)* обойтись без прокси-объектов и, например, просто написать ручную сериализацию для всех **ваших объектов, которые используют объекты из сторонних библиотек.** В соответствующих методах `serialize` и `deserialize` вы должны будете *записать нужные вам поля из объектов в поток, или, соответственно, сконструировать эти объекты из потока.*

---

#### Update

---

*Более подробное объяснение первого способа.*

Пусть есть некоторый класс `Entity`:

```
// Не реализует интерфейс Serializable
public class Entity {
    ...
}

public class EntitySerializableProxy extends Entity implements Serializable {
    private Entity internalEntity;


    // Запроксифицированные вызовы методов `Entity`, которые
    // переадресуют вызов к `internalEntity`.
    // ..........


    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        // Ручная реализация writeObject, записывающая поля `internalEntity`.
    }

    // Аналогично для `readObject`.
}
```

**Понятно, что прокси-объекты такого типа можно использовать везде, где мы бы использовали просто объект `Entity`.**

Отмечу также, что в случае, если есть много однотипных несериализующихся объектов, то такие вещи вполне как можно провернуть через дженерики.

*Для большего вникания в суть можете посмотреть следующее [**обсуждение**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95181/java-serialization-with-non-serializable-parts)*

Comment: обернуть ... .... ..например, EntitySerialiazbleProxy,  
Не понимаю, как это сделать. Если не тяжело, то можно ли по-подробнее?  
   
По поводу второго способа. Как я понимаю, вы предлагаете записывать данные объектов вручную, а потом, после десериализации, инициализировать их снова?   
  
Спасибо.

Comment: Плин. ГЕНИАЛЬНО и ПРОСТО. Спасибо!

Comment: не догоняю малеха "Запроксифицированные вызовы методов `Entity`, которые переадресуют вызов к `internalEntity`." КАК?)

Comment: Ну, скажем, если есть метод `Entity.connect()`, то надо будет написать

    void connect() {
        internalEntity.connect()
    }

Comment: без создания экземпляра Entity? почему они сразу не мапятся на родительские методы?

Comment: @Gorets

- Без создания. Конструктор в таком случае может выглядеть как `EntitySerializableProxy(Entity proxifiedEntity).` 

- В общем, классический **[GoF - Proxy][1]**

[1]: https://prof.hti.bfh.ch/due1/courses/c355/slides/patterns/proxy.pdf

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать  
То есть каждый метод нужно проксировать?