# Serializable

Tags: android, java

У меня есть объекты, которые я передаю между активити. Столкнулся с проблемой. У  меня есть объект из либы, делаю для него прокси-класс наследник от Serializable. интентом перекидываются нормально, но в новом активити он пустой. Может у кого есть какие догадки? 
Перед вопросом я нашел и почитал [Как сериализовать объект, не реализующий ни одного из интерфейсов сериализации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44815/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), я так с самого начала сделал, но чето не работает =)

Answer (score 3):

[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets) - ты вроде парень опытный, а говоришь непонятки.

В Android единственный способом (не считая конечно глобальных переменных и проч. мути) общения между Activity является механизм `Parcel`/`Parcelable`.

Там нет никакой кривизны или сырости - все работает отлично. Возможно у тебя есть какое-то недопонимание как это работает.

В твоем частном случае используй `Bundle.putSerializable()`

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("MY_OBJECT", myObject);
```

Comment: "This whole Parceable functionality looks unfinished (read: has bad design)." где-то со стека, на каком-то форуме уже обсуждал его реализацию и пришел, почти, к тому же выводу. Ну и обычная сериализацию объектом и их передача через интент тоже работает.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы корректно передать объект между Activity, нужно реализовать в его классе интерфейс Parcelable. Serializable в Android также поддерживается, но в первом случае потребуется меньше доработок в классе и с производительностью должно быть лучше. [В этой статье](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-activity.html) есть неплохой пример передачи объектов между Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Там вроде надо parcelable а не serializable.

Comment: знаю, имхо с parcelable больше играться и он сырой, а serializable хорошо работает